# Make selecting and writing into file faster in Groovy

Tags: optimization, groovy

I have this groovy code which is pretty simple:

```
sql.eachRow("""SELECT 
        LOOP_ID,
        FLD_1,
        ... 20 more fields 
        FLD_20  
        FROM MY_TABLE ORDER BY LOOP_ID"""){ res->

    if(oldLoopId != res.loop_id){
        oldLoopId = res.loop_id
        fileToWrite = new File("MYNAME_${type}_${res.loop_id}_${today.format('YYYYmmDDhhMM')}.txt")
        fileToWrite.append("20 fields header\n")
    }

    fileToWrite.append("${res.FLD_1}|${res.FLD_2}| ... |${res.FLD_20}\n");
}

}
```

it selects things from a table and writes to the database. For each new loop_id it creates a new file. The problem is it takes about 15 minutes to write 50mb file.

How do I make it faster?

Comment: File.append opens a writer, goes to the end of the file, and writes a line. Instead of this, create a writer for the new file and write to this (remember to close it before you create a new writer)

Answer (score 1):

Try writing to a [`BufferedWriter`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#newReader%28%29) instead of using `append` directly:

```
    sql.eachRow("""SELECT 
        LOOP_ID,
        FLD_1,
        ... 20 more fields 
        FLD_20  
        FROM MY_TABLE ORDER BY LOOP_ID""") { res ->

    def writer
    if (oldLoopId != res.loop_id) {
        oldLoopId = res.loop_id
        def fileToWrite = new File("MYNAME_${type}_${res.loop_id}_${today.format('YYYYmmDDhhMM')}.txt")
        if (writer != null)  { writer.close() }
        writer = fileToWrite.newWriter()
        writer.append("20 fields header\n")
    }

    writer.append("${res.FLD_1}|${res.FLD_2}| ... |${res.FLD_20}\n");
```

`File::withWriter` automagically close the resources, but to use it you'd need to do way more trips do DB, getting all the `loop_id` and fetching the data for each one.

---

The following script:

```
f=new File("b.txt")
f.write ""
(10 * 1024 * 1024).times { f.append "b" }
```

Execution:

```
$ time groovy Appends.groovy

real    1m9.217s
user    0m45.375s
sys 0m31.902s
```

And using a `BufferedWriter`:

```
w = new File("/tmp/a.txt").newWriter()
(10 * 1024 * 1024).times { w.write "a" }
```

Execution:

```
$ time groovy Writes.groovy

real    0m1.774s
user    0m1.688s
sys 0m0.872s
```

Comment: I tried it and while it's faster it's still pretty slow. It takes 4 minutes per 50mb of data. Maybe it's going through cursor that's slow? Can I make it faster somehow?

Comment: You can comment the file write to check the speed, but i'm almost sure it is the file writing which is turning out slow

Comment: Shouldn't `def writer` go outside the closure, since it is to be shared by all invocations?